# WinRM scripting from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, perl, winrm

How to write a Perl script that runs on Linux and is able to remotely execute a script on a Windows Server via [WinRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384426%28VS.85%29.aspx) given the local Administrator credentials?

I'm looking for sample code using a Perl library equivalent to this [Ruby library for Windows Remote Management](https://github.com/WinRb/WinRM) or this [Python library for Windows Remote Management](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [openwsman](https://github.com/Openwsman/openwsman)? It has perl bindings and [supports WinRM](https://github.com/Openwsman/openwsman/wiki/winrm-over-openwsman-setup). Haven't used it myself though.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that package. Thanks for pointing to it. I'll investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/HugoMaza/WinRM-WinRSExec

It's Perl module that makes you able to remotely execute scripts on a Windows Server via WinRM.